# the order of proper noun

Tags: meaning, differences

I would like to know if there is any difference in meaning between **Port of New York** and **New York port**.  In other words, does the order of proper noun make any difference in meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Three items.  First, there is a district that is referred to as the *Port of New York and New Jersey*.  Confusingly, this name is sometimes abbreviated to *[Port of New York](http://www.worldportsource.com/ports/USA_NY_Port_of_New_York_68.php)*

> [The Port of New York and New Jersey](https://www.panynj.gov/port/about-port.html) is the gateway to one of the most
>   concentrated and affluent consumer markets in the world. It is the
>   largest port on the East Coast, and the third-largest in the nation.
>
> In 2016, the Port of New York and New Jersey handled 3,602,508 cargo
>   containers, valued at nearly $200 billion. These volumes allowed the
>   port to maintain its position as the busiest on the East Coast with
>   nearly 30 percent of the total market share.

More specifically,

> [The Port of New York and New Jersey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_of_New_York_and_New_Jersey) is the port district of the New
>   York-Newark metropolitan area, encompassing the region within
>   approximately a 25-mile (40 km) radius of the Statue of Liberty
>   National Monument. It includes the system of navigable waterways in
>   the estuary along 650 miles (1,050 km) of shoreline in the vicinity of
>   New York City and northeastern New Jersey, as well as the region's
>   airports and supporting rail and roadway distribution networks.

Second, cruise lines sometimes refer to [Manhattan Cruise Terminal](https://www.ncl.com/sites/default/files/Port%20Directions_New%20York.pdf) as the *Port of New York*.  Also, [here](http://www.cruisin.me/cruise-port-tracker/united-states/new-york-new-york.php), for instance.  However, besides the cruise terminal in Manhattan, there are also nearby cruise terminals in Brooklyn and New Jersey and cruise lines are not shy about referring to these three ports collectively as the *[Port of New York](http://traveltips.usatoday.com/port-new-york-cruise-ship-information-18516.html)*.

Finally, if you are simply talking about a [New York port](https://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/ports/index.html?port=ny), there are a lot of them.  In addition, to the bigger ports which the cruise lines use, there are many, many smaller ports.  Ships give tours and take passengers in and out of Manhattan as part of their daily commute - there's the ferry to Staten Island as well as many private commuter services by ship.  Plus, there are many boats for private, non-commercial use.  *New York port* would need more context to be understandable.  Actually, that's true even if you knew the location was the New York City area.  If you could potentially mean any port in New York State, that's even more broad and definitely would need a lot more context to be clear what port you mean by *New York port*.

Comment: Maybe Port of New York was a confusing example.  I just want to know if the order of proper noun makes any difference in meaning.  Thank you, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

While there is a difference in the meaning, it quickly fades away in common usage.

**Port of New York** is the same in meaning as **New York's port**. It refers to a port which serves/belongs/lies in New York. A similar construction would be `House of Peter`. It refers to a house that belongs to the names man. This type of construction, `Common Noun` of `Proper Noun` is more common in geographical entities. For example, the City of Gondor, Valley of the Incas etc.

**New York port**, on the other hand, is comparable to `Peter house`, which does not make sense. It should rather be `Peter's house` or `the house of Peter`. However, with a lot of usage, people start to associate `Peter house` with the house that belongs to Peter.

Note that this is different from Amazon river or Cambridge University, in which case, Amazon and Cambridge are the names of the river and university respectively.